# Replace a image with a rotated image in file location - android

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camera, exif

when an image is captured on camera, I am using a ExifConverter to rotate the image correctly.

I want to replace the file in the uri/path with the rotated image so this path can be sent to the uploader class which will upload the image using the path to the api.

apologies if I did not make it clear

- photo captured
- I get the uri in activityResult
- rotate the image using EXIF
- WANT TO REPLACE THE FILE IN THE URI WITH THE NEW IMAGE

  ```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    hideScreen.visibility = View.GONE
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        uploadedImageCount++
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            this.requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(mUri!!)
        )

        val path =
            "" + this.requireContext().externalCacheDir + "/utility_bill.jpg"

        val rotatedBitmap = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(path, bitmap)

       //AFTER THE I GET THE ROTATEDBITMAP I WANT TO REPLACE THE FILE WITH THE NEW IMAGE SO IT HAS THE RIGHT IMAGE. IS THIS POSSIBLE

        //Add utility bill page
        val billItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.utility_bill_photo_list_item, null)
        billItem.id = View.generateViewId()
        utilityBillPhotoList.addView(billItem)
        utilityBillPhotoLayoutFlow.addView(billItem)
        resetAddPagePosition()
        setupUtilityBill(billItem, rotatedBitmap, utilityBillPhotoList.indexOfChild(billItem))

        fileType = "JPEG"
        startUtilityUploadProcess(path, "utility_bill.jpg", fileType)
    }
  ```

}

For reference this is the ExifUtils

```
class ExifUtil {
    companion object {
        fun rotateBitmap(src: String, bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
            try {
                val orientation: Int = getExifOrientation(src)
                if (orientation == 1) {
                    return bitmap
                }
                val matrix = Matrix()
                when (orientation) {
                    2 -> matrix.setScale(-1f, 1f)
                    3 -> matrix.setRotate(180f)
                    4 -> {
                        matrix.setRotate(180f)
                        matrix.postScale(-1f, 1f)
                    }
                    5 -> {
                        matrix.setRotate(90f)
                        matrix.postScale(-1f, 1f)
                    }
                    6 -> matrix.setRotate(90f)
                    7 -> {
                        matrix.setRotate(-90f)
                        matrix.postScale(-1f, 1f)
                    }
                    8 -> matrix.setRotate(-90f)
                    else -> return bitmap
                }
                return try {
                    val oriented =
                        Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
                    bitmap.recycle()
                    oriented
                } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    bitmap
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return bitmap
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        private fun getExifOrientation(src: String): Int {
            var orientation = 1
            try {
                val exif = ExifInterface(src);
                orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    1
                );
            } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: NoSuchMethodException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: InstantiationException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: InvocationTargetException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return orientation
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
R

Edit

package io.ohme.android.util

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.net.Uri
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap
import android.widget.Toast
import io.ohme.android.energy.utility.model.UtilityBillModel
import io.ohme.android.energy.utility.viewmodel.UploadBaseViewModel
import okhttp3.*
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody
import java.io.File

```
class UploadUtility(val viewModel: UploadBaseViewModel) {
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    fun uploadFile(sourceFilePath: String, uploadedFileName: String? = null, model: UtilityBillModel) {
        uploadFile(File(sourceFilePath), uploadedFileName, model)
    }

    private fun uploadFile(sourceFile: File, uploadedFileName: String? = null, model: UtilityBillModel) {
        Thread {
            val mimeType = getMimeType(sourceFile)
            if (mimeType == null) {
                return@Thread
            }
            val fileName: String = uploadedFileName ?: sourceFile.name
            try {
                val requestBody: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("key", model.fieldsToUseInPost.key)
                    .addFormDataPart("acl", model.fieldsToUseInPost.acl)
                    .addFormDataPart("Content-Type", model.fieldsToUseInPost.ContentType)
                    .addFormDataPart("x-amz-meta-ohmeid", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzMetaOhmeId)
                    .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Credential", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzCredential)
                    .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Algorithm", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzAlgorithm)
                    .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Date", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzDate)
                    .addFormDataPart("Policy", model.fieldsToUseInPost.Policy)
                    .addFormDataPart("X-Amz-Signature", model.fieldsToUseInPost.XAmzSignature)
                    .addFormDataPart("file", fileName, sourceFile.asRequestBody(mimeType.toMediaTypeOrNull()))
                    .build()

                val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(model.s3Host).post(requestBody).build()
                val response: Response = client.newCall(request).execute()

               if (response.isSuccessful) {
                   viewModel.onUploadSuccessful()
                } else {
                   viewModel.onUploadFailed()
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                viewModel.onUploadFailed()
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private fun getMimeType(file: File): String? {
        var type: String? = null
        val filePath = file.path
        var extension: String? = ""

        val i = filePath.lastIndexOf('.')
        if (i > 0) {
            extension = filePath.substring(i + 1)
        }
        if (extension != null) {
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
        }
        return type
    }
}
```

Picasso to display the image

```
 Picasso.get().load(url)
            .apply { placeholderRes?.let { placeholder(it) } }
            .apply { if (resizeWidthRes != null && resizeHeightRes != null) resizeDimen(resizeWidthRes, resizeHeightRes) }
            .apply { if (convertToCircle) transform(CircleTransformation()) }
            .into(imageView)
```

Comment: `when an image is captured on camera, I am using a ExifConverter to rotate the image correctly.` Why would you? If it is a jpg file the exif info on orientation will tell every software how to handle the file. You can not say that the image is rotated wrong or correct to begin with.

Comment: when I display the image captured from camera, it is rotated. once I use the exifUtils it displays correctly

Comment: And your upload code should just upload the file and should have no idea about the type of file. Be it a docx, a jpg, a png or pdf or whatever.

Comment: I want to send this bitmap to API but as it is based on the filepath, I want to replace the image in filepath with the new bitmap,

Comment: @blackapps thanks for responding, I have updated the question with uploadUtility file for reference

Comment: `when I display the image captured from camera, it is rotated. ` Then you do it wrong. Adapt that code. But do not change your jpg file as it is a perfect file. Everybody else should be able to handle it. So just upload unchanged to server. The ones who use it from server will handle the file correctly.

Comment: oh okay, it is basically the android app itself which gets it and displays it using Picasso, so this is how I use picasso to display the image.    Picasso.get().load(url)
            .apply { placeholderRes?.let { placeholder(it) } }
            .apply { if (resizeWidthRes != null && resizeHeightRes != null) resizeDimen(resizeWidthRes, resizeHeightRes) }
            .apply { if (convertToCircle) transform(CircleTransformation()) }
            .into(imageView)

Comment: As far as i can see UploadUtility uploads the file unchanged. This is good. Who is using that file from server? Any software can handle jpg files with exif irientation infirmation. Well they should. So what is the probkem? Only you displaying the fike wrong?

Comment: I added  .apply { rotate(90F) } but that did not work for landscape images. and I donot thing adding  .apply { rotate(90F) } is right and this should be based on the EXIFUITLS. not sure how to use EXIFUTIL.kt with picasso

Comment: And do NOT post code in comments. Use your post and a new code block if you wanna show your code.

Comment: yes that is right @blackapps displaying the file is wrong using picasso

Comment: If you would have told that in the first lines of your post we would have know why you take all this effort. If Picasso can not handle normal jpg files then better use a different library. Or do it yourself.

Comment: But .. you should be able of course to rotate the beast and write it to the original file. And you try it. But you did not tell what goes wrong. So what is it that you ask exactly,?

Comment: I am so sorry, if it is possible to rotate the image using picasso, that should be good enough. is that possible?

Comment: I dont know. I dont use Picasso.

Comment: what is the alternative u suggest please, I can replace picasso with something else which can do the job

Comment: Do it yourself i said. And there is Glide. I dont use Glide either.

Comment: any code you can suggest to do it by myself please

Comment: Well you can rotate a bitmap already. So what is the problem? Assign that bitmap to your ImageView. Maybe you should also rescale yet first.